# Blink / fade out to where the text-cursor is - Effect?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, cursor

I just installed an application (MousePosé)(which many of you will love) to show me where my mousecursor is, after pressing a shortcut,

However: very often when I'm programming, especially after CMD-Tab, I can't remember/see where my text-cursor is.

Does there exists an application that fades out the screen, until at the point of where the text-cursor is, like MousePose does with the mouse cursor?

In fact, it's like an Lightbox effect, where your whole screen gets fade-out and only the thing that matters (your text-cursor) shows in perfect glory, with no dimmed light.

Just like this, but when with the text-cursor, instead of the mouse-cursor

[image: Example]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a program that works system-wide, but if you use the terminal moderately, [iterm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) has this feature. Pressing Command-/ once will show the cursor with some screen fade, and pressing and holding it will white out everything on screen but the cursor.

[image: Fade]
[image: Whiteout]

Alternatively, not the same as fading, but there might be a way to have your text editor highlight vertical and horizontal columns. (Here's a plugin for [sublime](https://github.com/chancedai/sublime-cross)).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm really looking for a system-wide application. Since the text-cursor is something native of the OS, I guess it shouldn't be that hard. Same like the Mouse-cursor